# How can you format a number value to a string in Spark AR using patches?

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I'm trying to take number values from patches and format them into 2D text. I've tried using the patches module and have followed the following code I've seen floating around:

```
const Scene = require('Scene');
const Patches = require('Patches');

(async function () {
  const numberFormat = '{0}';
  const number = Patches.getScalarValue('number');
  
  Patches.setStringValue('value', number.format(numberFormat));
})();
```

[image: number to string test]

Instead of getting text output, it returns blank in the 2d text field.
I've looked in the console and the only warning I get is "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not a function."

I don't see exactly why it's not working. Is this not how it's done in the current API for scripting?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you forget to add "await":

```js
//here----------V
const number = await Patches.getScalarValue('number');
```